# Ajax ComboBox not rendering correctly when in asp:panel that starts as display:none

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, combobox

I have an Ajax ComboBox in an asp:panel.  The panel has my CssClass="hide" assigned which includes "display:none".

The user can click on another element that fires a JavaScript function which toggles the panel between CssClass="hide" and CssClass="show" ("show" includes "width:100%" which causes all controls in the panel to display **except the arrow image** on the ComboBox

IF I set the panel to start life with CssClass="show" everything displays correctly.  I can then use that function to change it to CssClass="hide" then back to CssClass="show" and everything still looks correct!

Your help is appreciated.

--------- My ASPX --------

```html
        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tabcontainerProject" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="1">
            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tpnlUpdateInformation" runat="server" HeaderText="Update Information">
                <ContentTemplate>
                     <span id="spanPositions" class="lnkempty" onclick="togglepnlPositions();">Project Team</span>
                      <br />
                      <asp:Panel ID="pnlPositions" runat="server" cssclass="hide">   
                          <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cbxOwner" runat="server"
                               DataSourceID="sqlOwner" DataTextField="Owner" DataValueField="Owner"
                               DropDownStyle="DropDown" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
                               ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText" CssClass="AquaStyle"
                               AutoPostBack="false">
                          </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
                      </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

--------- My JavaScript --------

```js
var stickypnlPositions = 0
function togglepnlPositions() {
    pnlPositions = document.getElementById('MainContent_tabcontainerProject_tpnlUpdateInformation_pnlPositions');
    if (stickypnlPositions === 0) {
        pnlPositions.setAttribute('class', 'show');
        stickypnlPositions = 1;
    } else {
        pnlPositions.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
        stickypnlPositions = 0;
    }
}
```

--------- My CSS --------

```css
.AquaStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(../Images/Ajax/Aqua/aqua-bg.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    border: 0px none;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 8px;
    /* font-size: 11px; */
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 150px;
}

.AquaStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button {
    background-image: url(../Images/Ajax/Aqua/aqua-arrow.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    border: 0px none;
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.AquaStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist {
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Jaydeep.  I've added snippets.  I'm starting to think my only option will be to change width/height to 'appear' to hide the panel, but I really wanted the speed of a client-side solution... (This may have been complicated by the fact that the panel is within an Ajax TabContainer/TabPanel)